# Отсутствие перевода количества вопросов по меткам

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

При отображении [таблицы меток](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular) отсутствует перевод для текста с кол-вом вопросов по меткам, а также для их хинта:

[image: questions tagged]